# Can't vertically align to the center <input> and <button> despite being inline-level elements

Tags: html, css

```css
.searchbar {
display: block;
border: 1px solid red
}

.searchbar input[type=text] {
float: left;
width: 80%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 30px;
display: inline-block;
outline: none;
border: 3px solid black;
padding: 16px;
margin: 6px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchbar button {
width: 16%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
padding: 16px;
margin: 6px;
border:none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'searchbar'>
<form>
<input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Click here'>
<button type = 'button'>Search</button>
</form>
</div>
```

In order to align both elements vertically, I used `vertical-align: middle` and, according to [CSS-TRICKS](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/), it works with inline-level elements. Despite setting their `display` values to `inline-block`, it doesn't seem to work . As you may have already noticed, `<input>` isn't aligned to the center as if it had not effect. In fact, if I were to delete `vertical-align: middle`, it would look the same. Also, it seems that `<input>` bottom margin isn't working. However, it should since it's a block-level element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this styling:

```css
.searchbar form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here is the snippet:

```css
.searchbar {
display: block;
border: 1px solid red
}

.searchbar form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.searchbar input[type=text] {
float: left;
width: 80%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius: 30px;
display: inline-block;
outline: none;
border: 3px solid black;
padding: 16px;
margin: 6px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchbar button {
width: 16%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: inline-block;
padding: 16px;
margin: 6px;
border:none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'searchbar'>
<form>
<input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Click here'>
<button type = 'button'>Search</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going with the approach you explained above you can use `flex`.

Just add display flex to your form and let the `margin:auto` do the rest.

```css
.searchbar {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red
}

.searchbar input[type=text] {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchbar button {
    width: 16%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 6px;
    border: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='searchbar'>
    <form class="d-flex">
        <input type='text' placeholder='Click here'>
        <button type='button'>Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Change the margin to auto instead of `6px` and add display flex to form.